# Copy data that lies outsde Autofilter Range

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to create an excel document which takes pasted data from another piece of software, and generate reports based on said data.

The data comes in the format

```
ID, YYYY, MM, DD, HH, MM, SS, Day
```

Data arrives in pairs. So one valid entry would be:

```
1 2017 8 24 09 44 52 4
1 2017 8 24 10 50 00 4
```

The user then has access to the full raw dump of data, or can create a report.

If the user wants to create a report: the user selects a date from comboboxes and selects if they want all data from: BEFORE, all data AFTER, or all data ON their selected date, from optionbuttons.

Here is an example of the filter code, for BEFORE SELECTED DATE.
This will filter my data as i need, and copy the filtered data into the report schema.

```
If OptionButton1 = True Then     'Before Selected Date 
  With Worksheets("PasteData")
    .Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<=" & ComboBox1.Value
    .Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="<=" & Mid(ComboBox2.Value, 1, 2)
    .Range("A1:H1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="=" & ComboBox3.Value 
    .Range("A2:H" & LastRow).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Report").Range("A6")
  End With
End If
```

The trouble i'm having is, sometimes the data can span over two days, i.e.

```
ID| YYYY | MM | DD | HH | MM | SS | Day
--|------|----|----|----|----|----|----
1 | 2017 | 08 | 24 | 23 | 30 | 00 | 01
1 | 2017 | 08 | 25 | 02 | 00 | 00 | 02
```

Now, if i was to filter by day, and choose all data BEFORE and INCLUDING the 24th day of august, I would then lose the other entry in the pair.

Obvioulsy I need something to check if dates roll over into another day

What I think I need is something like:

```
If Entry1ID1 = Entry1ID2 __ ' Entry ID's Match
    AND Entry1Day1 <> Entry1Day2 'Entry days are different Then
  copy selection + 1
```

EDIT: I think if I select before i Copy the data over, I can write a FOR Loop, to loop through each selection in the range. i.e:

```
for each selection in range
  if selection - 1 ID = selectionID then
    selection -1 . select
  Else 
    selection + 1 . select
Next
```